# Update one element of State React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, state

I have a problem, a bit hard to explain.

I use Hooks to set a state, from the data I receive from my API.
I display it on my frontend, no problem.

I would like to update ONE value, from ONE element.

Here is my full component :

```
import { UidContext } from "../components/AppContext"
import { totalIncome, totalFees, balance } from "./balance.utils"
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import axios from "axios"

export default function Balance() {
    const uid = useContext(UidContext)
    const [userWalletIncomes, setUserWalletIncomes] = useState('')
    const [userWalletFees, setUserWalletFees] = useState('')
    const [formIncomes, setformIncomes] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (uid !== null) {
            axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/balance/${uid}`)
                .then((res) => {
                    setUserWalletIncomes(res.data[0].incomes)
                    setUserWalletFees(res.data[0].fees)
                })
        }
    }, [uid])

    return (
        <div className="h-screen">
            <section className="border my-2 w-max md:w-11/12 mx-auto text-center">
                <h1 className="text-3xl my-5">Revenus</h1>

                {formIncomes === false && (
                    Object.entries(userWalletIncomes).map(([key, value]) => {
                        return (
                            <div className="text-left mx-auto flex" key={key}>
                                <p className="w-32 border p-1 capitalize">{key} :</p>
                                <p onClick={(e) => setformIncomes(true)} className="w-32 border p-1 text-green-500">{value}€</p>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                )}
                {formIncomes === true && (
                    Object.entries(userWalletIncomes).map(([key, value]) => {
                        return (
                            <div className="text-left mx-auto flex" key={key}>
                                <p className="w-32 border p-1">{key} :</p>
                                <input className="w-32 border p-1 text-green-500"
                                    value={value}
                                    onChange={(e) => setUserWalletIncomes(value)} />
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                )}
            </section>
        </div>
    )
}
```

So, when I click on my `<p>`, it transforms to an input. Then I would like to modify the amount of income, and set it to the state.

For information, my collection (mongo) look like this :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60c763df3d260204865d2069"
    },
    "incomes": {
        "salaire1": 1130,
        "salaire2": 640,
        "Prime": 90
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "fees": {
        "Box": 35,
    }
}
```

So I need to update only the income category, and only the amount from the key selected. I don't know if I'm clear...

Any idea ?

Additional info : My setUserWalletIncomes in the input erase all the state, and replace it with the only value from the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of object destructuring to do that

```
setUserWalletIncomes({...userWalletIncomes, incomes: {...userWalletIncomes.incomes, [keySelected]: value}});
```

See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for more info on the matter.

Edit: You already have it thanks to your Object.entries func. See below for full code.

```
<input className="w-32 border p-1 text-green-500"
                                    value={value}
                                    onChange={(e) => setUserWalletIncomes({...userWalletIncomes, incomes: {...userWalletIncomes.incomes, [key]: e.target.value}})} />
```

Comment: And probably he wants to take the new value from the `onChange`-event by using `e.target.value`?

Comment: I assumed by typing `value` that he knew how to retrieve it, same goes for `keySelected`. I was giving the general approach rather than an exact solution that could be copypasted.

Comment: Hello. Thank you ! I just don't see how I can select the current key ? Which you named "keySelected" ?

Comment: @schogges yes x), I need the onChange to change the value, and set it in the state at the right place

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals Ok that's what I did. But unfortunately, it does not work :/. It creates a new line in the state, instead of replacing the ancient one :/. I'm new with Hooks so it is a bit hard for me ^^

Comment: Ok, I fount the solution. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, what was it? :)

Answer (score 0):

You just want only one map like this:

```
Object.entries(userWalletIncomes).map(([key, value]) => {
    return (
      <div className="text-left mx-auto flex" key={key}>
        <p
          className={`w-32 border p-1 ${
            formIncomes === key ? "capitalize" : ""
          }`}
        >
          {key} :
        </p>
        {formIncomes === key ? (
          <input
            className="w-32 border p-1 text-green-500"
            value={value}
            onChange={(e) =>
              setUserWalletIncomes({
                ...userWalletIncomes,
                [key]: e.target.value,
              })
            }
          />
        ) : (
          <p
            onClick={(e) => setformIncomes(key)}
            className="w-32 border p-1 text-green-500"
          >
            {value}€
          </p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  });
```

Comment: Hello. There is an error in that code, I can't find where. Error is : Balance.js: Unterminated regular expression. (60:14)

Comment: Can you show the line has problem: line 60

Comment: the line 60 is just under your last line. It is the closing section tag. So I guess one it is one bracket missing ?

Comment: I found the error, but your code make my section disappear when I click on it x)